# How to execute FOR loop in PHP for several ranges

Tags: php

When i try to catch data from a large API with PHP and SQL, it only give me the first 20 rows data. So I have to run the 'FOR' loop in PHP for every 20 rows, separately, to get all of the rows. Let's say we have a total of 100 rows.
My code that is working, looks like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i< 20; $i++){
 echo "The number is: $i <br>";
}
```

but I want it to, separately, run for 20-40 , 40-60 , 60-80 , 80-100.

Is there a solution, like the one below?!

```
$value1 = Array(0,20,40,60,80)
$value2 = Array(20,40,60,80,100)
for ($i = $value1; $i< $value2; $i++){
 echo "The number is: $i <br>";
}
```

Update:
At the end, i need all 100 rows to be caught like this `[0,1,2,...,18,19],[20,21,22,...,38,39].[40,41,...],...,[...99,100]`. So i can store all data rows in MySQL database. As i said when i run all 100 rows at once, it only gives me the first 20 rows, because of API limits, i guess. Thanks

Comment: Just have an outer `while` loop that runs while there are more records, and have `$base += 20;` and use `$base+$i` within the inner loop.

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i += 20)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a solution, like the one below?!

Your solution will go into an infinite loop.

---

Based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035652/how-to-execute-for-loop-in-php-for-several-ranges/69035943?noredirect=1#comment122011542_69035943), I've refactored my answer.

I'd use a:

- `do...while` that loops until you've gotten all the rows
- An inner `for` to loop over each row individual

---

The below script will show each `0-100` and separates each `20`.

Those `(skip)` indicates that I've manually removed a part of the output to reduce the size.

```php
<?php

$rows = 100;
$part = 20;
$amountRetrieved = 0;

// Outer loop
do {

    // Get data
    echo "Get rows; $amountRetrieved <--> " . ($amountRetrieved + $part) . PHP_EOL;

    // Inner loop
    for ($i = 0; $i < $part; $i++) {
        
        // Show inner loop value
        echo "Inner: " . ($amountRetrieved + $i) . PHP_EOL;
    }  

    // Bump counter  
    $amountRetrieved += $part;

} while ($amountRetrieved < $rows);
```

```
Get rows; 0 <--> 20
Inner: 0
Inner: 1
(skip)
Inner: 17
Inner: 18
Inner: 19
Get rows; 20 <--> 40
Inner: 20
Inner: 21
(skip)
Inner: 37
Inner: 38
Inner: 39
Get rows; 40 <--> 60
Inner: 40
Inner: 41
(skip)
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBRa8IwFIWfd3/FQXxYKU63x7VuMBibICjzB0iwGQnUJmSpfRB/e71JtSB1ecm9J7nnfIlVtm3zd6ss0diZ5g9zPM9mGY2tcJ6bl1CLvakr/yO90/IgC5ZZpekUq9pLh9IYS4XBkQi8WP@SHoXwIvZypwxGQQoBGQZ2@WTyhhGe8Dg4ShFBEj5cf6@3n6tl1ocsquoaHpRf49hARzjwnnejoU7ThOFwWbF4YIONMg1074KDKGvZX@uwY8jr/3T6Bi3MnTjhivhR7y12YYgzuuChyfwCSnRCo3Qp7yTxY8LnJVnbngE)

Comment: Thanks 0Stone0, but what i'm looking for is something like: {0,1,2,3,...,19,},{20,21,22,...,29},... .

Comment: Thank you very much buddy. It did the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
$max_values = 100;
$max_row = 20;
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

while( ( $j*max_row + $i) < $max_values ) ){    
  for ($i = 0; $i < $max_row; $i++){
    $row = $j*max_row + $i;
    echo 'Row is: '.$row;
  }
  $j++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this solves your problem

```
$repeat = 4;
$times = 1;
$num = 0;
while($times <= $repeat){
    $times += 1;
    $num += 20;
    for ($num; $i<($num + 20); $i++){
        //do something
        echo "I'm number: " . $i . "\n";
    }
}
```